# Typescript :Getter can't return array with custom type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im getting errors when trying to return array with custom type from getter. Here is the error message:

```
Type 'Expense[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Expense': name, cost, priority
```

And here is my code:

```
import Expense from '../interfaces/expence';

class User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  totalCost: number;
  private expenses: Expense[];
  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = this.lastName;
  }
  set userExpenses(expence: Expense) {
    this.expenses = [...this.expenses, expence]
    this.totalCost += expence.cost
  }
  get userExpenses() {
    return this.expenses
  }
}
export default User;

interface Expense {
  name: string
  cost: number;
  priority: string,
}

export default Expense;
```

Comment: Is the whole code from one single file?

Comment: Getter/seter must have the same type. In your case you want the setter to take an item and the getter to return the array. this is not possible.

Comment: No, they are from separate files.Is there an alternative  way i could do this.

Comment: On a side note, you've got typos: `expence` instead of `expense`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is both `get` and `set` must have the same type. In your case, `set` is working on single Expense object and `get` is returning `Expense[]`.

Better solution would be create a append method for setter, as following code would not make sense

```
user.userExpenses = new Expense("1", 100, "1"); \\ it appends to expenses array
```

Here's what I would do

```
class User {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
totalCost:number;
private expenses: Expense[] ;
constructor(firstName: string,lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = this.lastName;
}

set userExpenses(expences: Expense[]) { //assignment
    this.expenses = [...expences];   
    this.expenses.forEach(e => this.totalCost += e.cost);
}

get userExpenses() {
    return this.expenses
}

addExpences(expences: Expense[]) {  //append
    expences.forEach(e => this.totalCost += e.cost);
    this.expenses = [...this.expenses, ...expences];   
}
```

}

Comment: Great solution. It's quite annoying how get/set have to be the same type, however, it would defeat the purpose of TypeScript if it wasn't!